# Why isn't the User Agent being modified using the Chrome API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using the [Google Chrome Extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/), I am attempting to modify the User-Agent header that is sent with HTTP requests with the following code:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener((details) => {
    let reqHeaders = details.requestHeaders;
    if (reqHeaders) {
        reqHeaders.forEach((header) => {
            if (header.name == "User-Agent") {
                header.value = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36"
                console.log(header.value) //Extension does change the value but it is never applied
            }
        });
    }
    return {requestHeaders: reqHeaders}; //This should apply the new value but doesn't
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["requestHeaders"]);
```

My User-Agent according to the Chrome Network Monitor: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

I have read over the documentation numerous times and have been unable to find a wrongdoing in my code. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Your code is incorrect in MV2 as it lacks `'blocking'` in the last array, however it won't work in MV3 anyway as this mode is not supported there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To any future users who have stumbled upon this problem, I have found a solution. The `webRequest` API callbacks are only supported when the extension is added to the `ExtensionInstallForcelist`. The API isn't deprecated (yet) which is why I originally thought my code would work. You are now being encouraged to use the [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) API as a replacement.

The `webRequest` API gives you more control over how you process request information programatically, but the `declarativeNetRequest` has a higher priority, less security restrictions, and less memory usage.

Comment: Please mark your answer as "accepted" (the OP can mark any answer as "accepted", even if he's the one who wrote it)

Comment: @ThomasMueller I appreciate the tip though SO gives me a notification saying I can only accept my own answer 2 days after I have posted it.